# Add plugin method to Moment.js declaration in Flow?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, flowtype

Is there a way to extend/add to an existing declaration using Flow?

Specifically, in this case we're using both [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), and [a plugin that adds a format method to the Duration object](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format).

I located a [third-party type declaration for momentjs](https://github.com/marudor/flowInterfaces/tree/master/packages/iflow-moment) at FlowInterfaces, but (naturally) it doesn't have the extra method provided by the plugin.

Currently to solve this I've duplicated the entire declaration file with an added line for the new method, but ideally there'd be a way to update an existing declaration, something like:

```
type moment$MomentOptions += {
    format(format: ?string): string; // moment-duration-format
}
```

...but with a nicer syntax :)

So my question is does such a thing exist for Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, without overriding the whole definition, this it not possible [currently](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/396).

For the time being, you can also extend `moment$Moment` and use this type instead in your project. But it will require to cast most of the results. Therefore, not sure if it is a better solution; but it might help in some cases.

```
declare class moment$MyMoment extends moment$Moment {
  format(format: ?string): string;
}

function fn(m: moment$MyMoment) {
  m.format(''); // OK
}

const m = ((moment(new Date()): any): moment$MyMoment);
fn(m); // OK
```